# Django csv taking very long time Outputting CSV

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a model which has a text entry of about 90,000 and I am outputting Django CSV but it is not converting outputting CVS i left browser for half an hour aand no output.But the method i used it worked fine when data is low.

My method:-

```
def usertype_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="university_list.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    news_obj = Users.objects.using('cms').all()
    writer.writerow(['NAME', 'USERNAME', 'E-MAIL ID','USER TYPE','USER TYPE'])
    for item in news_obj:
        writer.writerow([item.name.encode('UTF-8'),item.username.encode('UTF-8'),item.email.encode('UTF-8'),
                             item.userTypeId.userType.encode('UTF-8'),item.universityId.name.encode('UTF-8')])


    return response
```

I have testing this for smaller data it worked but for very larger files it is not working.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Any large CSV files you generate should ideally be [streamed back to the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) you can find an example on how django handles it.
This is how I would do it:

```
import csv
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

class Echo(object):
    """An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
    interface.
    """
    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

def some_streaming_csv_view(request):
    """A view that streams a large CSV file."""
    # Generate a sequence of rows. The range is based on the maximum number of
    # rows that can be handled by a single sheet in most spreadsheet
    # applications.
    rows = (["Row {}".format(idx), str(idx)] for idx in range(165536))
    pseudo_buffer = Echo()
    news_obj = Users.objects.using('cms').all()
    writer = csv.writer(pseudo_buffer)
    response = StreamingHttpResponse((writer.writerow([item.name.encode('UTF-8'), item.username.encode('UTF-8'), item.email.encode('UTF-8'), item.userTypeId.userType.encode('UTF-8'), item.universityId.name.encode('UTF-8')]) for item in news_obj), content_type="text/csv")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="university_list.csv"'
    return response
```